# Counting path generating sentences in a specific formal language

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, computability-theory, computer-science, formal-languages

Given a formal grammar of a language or an Turing machine of the language, can we count the path that generating sentences of the language?

For example, we know that if the grammar is context-free and unambiguious , we have Schutzenberger-Chomsky theorem, by which we know the number of path is equivalent to the number of the sentence. Since grammars of languages may neither be context-free nor umabiguious, is there any formula or method that can counts the path generating sentences of a formal language? Obviously, the number of sentences may not equal to number of path generating sentences in such cases.

Comment: For an arbitrary Turing machine there is little or nothing that can be said.

Comment: I find the question hard to parse. Do you want the generating function for derivations of words using the grammar or the generating function for the language?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, thank you for comment, I want the generating function for derivations of words using the grammar, for language  there is a theorem that is Schutzenberger-Chomsky theorem hard to be extended